# How to slice some part of Google Map and show the sliced one in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to slice some part of Google Map and want to show it in a div. How can I do that? Is there any google apis?

I don't have any code but below example shows my requirement.

[image]

From the above map I want to slice below red color part and I want to put it in separate div.

[image]

Is it possible? If it is, then how can I do that? Any APIs?

Comment: Take a look at integrating geojson with gmaps and style it. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my understanding, Google maps does not separate regions into layers. One solution I can think of is using [Open Street Maps](http://openstreetmaps.org) to export your desired region into an SVG and using illustrator to remove the unnecessary content.

Comment: See, I want to do it in programmatic way.

Comment: In that case, it is not possible. A hacky solution would be to, as Nouphal suggested, to use GeoJSON to hide the rest of the map. Probably colour it white.